# POWERBI - Percentage being calculated incorrectly for a selection of multiple months

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 columns 'Total OPD Visits' and 'EMR Filled'. I must calculate 'EMR Usage %' as 'EMR Filled'/Total OP Visits'.
Here's how my matrix is set up:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxhtT.png)

Total OPD Visits' and 'EMR Filled' are columns of the table and 'EMR USAGE%' is a column made within BI.

There is a month slicer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRdsG.png)

When I select 1 month (say December) the values displayed are correct:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76i9b.png)

However, if there are multiple selections:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uinOq.png)

then the values shown are incorrect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Vdo.png)

What I want is for the % field to show the correct division:
[EMR FILLED (November+December)] / [TOTAL OPD VISITS (November+December]
instead of :
( [EMR FILLED (November)] / [TOTAL OPD VISITS (November] ) + ( [EMR FILLED (November+December)] / [TOTAL OPD VISITS (November+December] )

Now I'm aware that the aggregation for this column is set to sum, however, setting it to average will also not yield the wanted result.

I have tried various solutions presented by the PowerBI community on similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Measures (not Calculated Columns or Columns) for proper averages, percentages etc...

Create a new **Measure** like so:

```
EMR Usage % = 
  DIVIDE(
    SUM('YourTable'[EMR Filled]),
    SUM('YourTable'[Total OPD Visits])
  )
```